# If statements with emojis

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, emoji

I'm just starting javascript so I apologize if anything I say is unclear. I'm trying to write a function that see's if the var emoji is the same as a specified emoji. I have an else statement following it - as a fall through. ```

```
    function match1() {
   
    var emoji = document.getElementById("emoji");
   
    if (emoji == "&#128516"){
  
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "correct"; 
    
    }
    
    else {
      
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "not correct"; 
      document.getElementById("emoji").innerHTML = "&#128542";
    }
    
 }
```

Everything run's fine, except the if statement never actually happens, even when emoji does equal &#128516. Is that if statement something that will never work or have I just written it wrong?

Comment: `emoji ` will be a DOM element, assuming it exists in your DOM, not a string. Try `console.log(emoji.innerText)` or `emoji.innerHTML` and see what you get.

Comment: like 

`if (emoji.innerHTML == "&#128516"){
      
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "correct"; 
        
        } `

or 


`if ( console.log(emoji.innerText) == "&#128516"){
      
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "correct"; 
        
        }`
?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, when you get the emoji, it's not the HTML escape chars, but the actual rendered HTML, as you can see:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("emoji").innerHTML);
```

```html
<p id="emoji">&#128516</p>
```

Anyways, to compare an emoji, just do it like you always do in an if statement, but use the rendered version of the emoji in the JavaScript, not the escape chars. Also, as someone pointed out in the comments, `document.getElementById("emoji")` will return something like `<p id="emoji"></p>`, not just the content. You can get the content with `innerHTML` or `innerText`.

Here's a working example of your question:

```js
function match1() {
  var emoji = document.getElementById('emoji').innerHTML;
  if (emoji === "") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "correct";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "not correct";
    document.getElementById("emoji").innerHTML = "&#128542";
  }
}
match1();
```

```html
<p id="emoji">&#128516</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, that makes a lot more sense! the IDE I'm using right now doesn't allow me to use the rendered version of the emoji, it just comes up as some boxes, is there anything you'd recommend? Thank you for the answer regardless, it was really helpful!!

Comment: @FaithLyman Just use the escape sequence for emoji instead. `"\u{1f600}" === ""`. Less problems with IDEs and file encodings.

Comment: Just use the other solution given in the comments.

Comment: Glad it helped. If it answered your question, could you select the answer as correct?

Comment: yep, when I found an IDE that let my add emojis to the script it worked as intended!!